# what does this error mean, and how do I fix it?CalledProcessError:

Tags: python, django

I'm on my way to deploy it, and I see two errors that I don't understand and I don't know how fix

```
  Command "/opt/python/run/venv/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-tNM7u6/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open
)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-pBGCvT-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --i
nstall-headers /opt/python/run/venv/include/site/python2.7/Pillow" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-tNM7u6/Pillow
  You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 8.1.1 is available.
  You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
  2016-03-18 10:49:14,342 ERROR    Error installing dependencies: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-z
ero exit status 1
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 22, in main
      install_dependencies()
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 18, in install_dependencies
      check_call('%s install -r %s' % (os.path.join(APP_VIRTUAL_ENV, 'bin', 'pip'), requirements_file), shell=True)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1 (Executor::NonZeroExitStat
us)
```

and

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-commandprocessor.log
-------------------------------------
      install_dependencies()
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 18, in install_dependencies
      check_call('%s install -r %s' % (os.path.join(APP_VIRTUAL_ENV, 'bin', 'pip'), requirements_file), shell=True)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1 (Executor::NonZeroExitStat
us)
```

I just don't know what the error means and where they come from. 
I'm using elastic beanstalk, and when I do eb create I get Your requirements.txt is invalid. Snapshot your logs for details.

Here's my requiremnets.txt

```
BeautifulSoup==3.2.1
Django==1.8.4
Django-Select2==5.7.1
Pillow==3.1.0
PyYAML==3.11
Unidecode==0.04.19
Whoosh==2.7.0
argparse==1.2.1
awsebcli==3.7.3
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.5.0.1
blessed==1.9.5
botocore==1.4.4
cement==2.4.0
colorama==0.3.3
cssselect==0.9.1
django-activity-stream==0.6.0
django-annoying==0.8.7
django-appconf==1.0.1
django-ckeditor==5.0.3
django-crispy-forms==1.6.0
django-embed-video==1.1.0
django-guardian==1.3.1
django-haystack==2.4.1
django-jsonfield==0.9.15
django-tastypie==0.13.0
django-userena==1.5.1
django-uuslug==1.1.7
docker-py==1.1.0
dockerpty==0.3.4
docopt==0.6.2
docutils==0.12
easy-thumbnails==2.3
enum34==1.1.2
futures==3.0.5
goose-extractor==1.0.25
html2text==2014.12.29
jieba==0.38
jmespath==0.9.0
lxml==3.5.0
nltk==3.1
pathspec==0.3.3
psycopg2==2.6.1
pyasn1==0.1.9
python-dateutil==2.4.2
python-mimeparse==0.1.4
python-slugify==1.2.0
requests==2.6.2
rsa==3.3
s3transfer==0.0.1
six==1.10.0
texttable==0.8.4
wcwidth==0.1.6
websocket-client==0.35.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Comment: what if you try to `pip install -r requirements.txt` locally? Does it install correctly?

Comment: yes locally everything is fine

Comment: @awwester locally its good

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is try and install that requirements.txt locally and see what happens. I tried that and there's a problem with `BeautifulSoup==3.2.1`. I'm not sure why that's happening, but that will be another issue.

The reason why it's not installing in AWS is because the requirements.txt file is not installing correctly, as you suspected.

Comment: locally every thing works fine, so requirements.txt has been installed correctly there...where do you see a problem regards to beautifulsoup?

Comment: hey try `pip uninstall BeautifulSoup` and then  `pip install BeautifulSoup==3.2.1` to install it fresh (similar to how AWS is installing it). I get an error with that install package, could be something wrong with the package - usually BeautifulSoup installs fine for me.

Comment: if that works fine, then I don't have any other suggestions :) But it is giving an error for me and it shouldn't be

Comment: beautifulsoup is giving you an error? is that what you're saying?/I don't think that's the problem I'm not gonna do that, thanks for the advice tho

Comment: yeah it is giving me an error on install. No problem, good luck!

Comment: wait did you get the same error when using elastic beanstalk?I'm getting above errors when I do eb create

Comment: I have gotten this error 3-4 times before while deploying to EB, it means that it can't install your requirements.txt. I haven't tried deploying to eb though with your requirements.txt

Comment: even after I installed new ones for pillow and bs, I still get the error. how did you solve the problem?